# I need to make a PUT request to a JSON file in an external API. I need to update specific fields

Tags: javascript, php, json, put

I have a JSON on an external API, and, in the documentation of the API, it instructs to use a `PUT` request to update records.  I have read a lot on this, but I haven't found an adequate amount of information.

I will do my best to provide you with the most info I can so you can help me, specifically.

I have the url stored in a variable: `$record`.

The documentation instructs to: Set the request body content as a json formatted array of record data. This is the “payload”.

It also provides an example:

```
{

“Name”: “Craig J. Peters”,

“Job Title”: “Director of Engineering”

}
```

I need to change specific fields.  How can I accomplish this using cURL and PHP?

I should mention: If this is easier with JavaScript, I am open to that as well.

Comment: you really should specify what you have tried so far

Comment: To be honest, I dont know what to try

Comment: @Matt be specific on your context for this `put` !!! is the code running in some back-end server or some front-end page ?  PHP is most usually a back-end technology while JS is mostly front-end.

Comment: It is a backend api for a database.  There are a lot of records, and I am trying to change a field to the value of an html text `input`.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to check [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/) as a starting point -

http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#body

Comment: Is this not possible with plain php?

Comment: link-only answers are rarely useful in the immediate to OP, and often become deprecated as the links falls into www oblivion.